# Identify this dominos game

Tags: identify-this-game, dominoes

I played a game with a friend a few years ago and I can't remember what we called it.

The game used a pack of dominos however you placed them around a central card. I believe it was a hexagon and required a double to start (although this may be incorrect).

As you placed your dominoes the game grew out in a star shape. As normal the game ended when a player managed to place all their dominoes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mexican train Dominos.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_Train)

It also goes as train dominos as well.

Comment: We called it something different but that's it exactly - thanks!

Comment: It is our favorite domino game at home. I am sadly very bad at it. I never could get the strategy as simple as it is.

Comment: I'm terrible at dominos full stop! I'll accept your answer as soon as I can (waiting for the required time).